# Can't add a cell to a row dynamicall

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is some of my aspx code:

```
<table class="agentsStyle" id="agentsTable" runat="server">
                 <tr id="agentsNames">
                     <td>
                         ahmad
                     </td>
                 </tr>
</table>
```

this is my c# code:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = agentName;
            cell.Attributes.Add("class", "d");
            agentsNames.Cells.Add(cell);
```

I got this error:

```
Error   12  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: Replace this `TableCell cell = new TableCell();` with this `HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi it works, write an answer to accept it please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
```

with this

```
HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [`HtmlTableCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `TableCell`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltablecellcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You also need to change the `Text` property to `InnerText`.

So try this:

```
HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = agentName;
cell.Attributes.Add("class", "d");
agentsNames.Cells.Add(cell);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

...

```
 HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
 cell.InnerText= "test";  //  change cell.Text to cell.InnerText
 cell.Attributes.Add("class", "d");
 agentsNames.Cells.Add(cell);
```